# apoc.uuid.install not registered for this database instance

Tags: neo4j, uuid, neo4j-apoc

I've installed the apoc plugin using neo4j desktop, according to those instructions: [https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/#:~:text=APOC%20Full%20can%20be%20installed,see%20the%20%22Installed%22%20message](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/#:%7E:text=APOC%20Full%20can%20be%20installed,see%20the%20%22Installed%22%20message).

I've created a new apoc.conf file in the conf folder (where the neo4j.conf is located) and added the line: `apoc.uuid.enabled=true` and saved.
I stopped my db and then restarted it.
also in the neo4j.conf file I have this line to enable procedures for apoc:
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=jwt.security.*,apoc.*

also have this in the conf file:
#dbms.security.procedures.allowlist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*,gds.*

when I run `RETURN apoc.create.uuid() AS uuid`;
I get a valid response.

also my neo4j version is 5.3, identical to the version I get when i ran: `RETURN apoc.version() AS output`;

but when I try to run: `CALL apoc.uuid.install('Person')`
YIELD label, installed, properties
RETURN label, installed, properties;
I get:
`There is no procedure with the name apoc.uuid.install registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.`

My goal is to create a uuid for every node created with the label Person, so I tried to run the query as it is in the actual [documentation](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-updates/uuid/) but the procedure is not recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be confusing, but APOC was split into core and extended version. The `apoc.create.uuid` is in core edition, but the `apoc.uuid.install` is in extended. Make sure to add both JARs into the plugin folder. You can find the extended version for Neo4j 5.3 here -> https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/tag/5.3.1